# Render views with actions from one controller into a view of a different controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to render a view that with actions from one view, into another controllers view.

I have a a view called `stocks.ctp` (using `StocksController`) that I want to render in `home.ctp` (`HomeController`) I thought I could just do `<?php echo $this->fetch('../Stocks/stocks'); ?>` in `home.ctp`, but that isn't working.

I've also tried putting `<?PHP $this->extend('stocks'); ?>` in `home.ctp` but that just overwrites the entire view and only renders `stocks.ctp`.

How can I display `stocks.ctp` inside `home.ctp`?

This is just an an example: Here is the

```
       <?php $this->start('stocks');?>
         <div>
            content
         </div>
        <?php $this->end(); ?>
```

And here is just and example of the `home.ctp` view.

```
      <div class="col-3">
            <h1>STOCK MARKET WOOOOO</h1>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('stocks'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <h1>Opinion</h1>
            <hr></hr>
        </div>
```

How can I render this properly? I've tried a bunch of solutions that I've found here but nothing has worked yet and I've tried the using cookbook's documentation but no luck. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about how to create elements in CakePHP documentation.
After create elements, you should be able to use them wherever you want in your application.

1. Create the element inside View/elements, ex: /View/elements/stocks.ctp
2. Request it in your home.ctp.

For example:

```
<?php

    echo $this->element('stocks');

?>
```

The element should be rendered.

Read about it here: [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html#elements)

Comment: cool, I'm looking at that now. I see I need to pass a variable into them, can I do this with a find method? In the documentation it says `<?php echo $this->element('helpbox',array("helptext" => "Oh, this text is very helpful."));?>` but can I do `<?php echo $this->element('helpbox',array("helptext" => $this->Post->find ('all'));?>`? Or do I do something like this `<?php echo $this->element('helpbox',array("helptext")); ?>` and then in in the helbox.ctp element I do `<?php $helptext = $this->requestAction('Posts/index/'); ?>`?

Comment: The find methods should be used in the controllers. The view need to contain just exhibition code. In your controller you can do: $posts = $this->Post->find('all'); $this->set('posts', $posts); Then $posts will be available in your view, so: $this->element('posts', array('data' => $posts)); Hope it helps. The requestAction is valid to, but you lose a little bit of performance due a new request. I prefer to set variables directly in the current controller action. You can read more about $this->requestAction here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction

Answer (score 0):

You should put this in your Homecontroller..
`$this->render('Stocks/stocks');`

Answer (score 0):

In your controllers action do

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

and at the end of your controller action do

```
$this->render('Stocks/stocks');
```